# Idea keymap on linux like windows

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, intellij-15

Is there any way to use the same keymap in intellij idea on linux like in windows? For example: pressing on mouse wheel is the same like ctrl+left click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mouse shortcut can be added to "show usages" action along with the key shortcut "Alt + Ctrl + F7" to achieve it. Though you'd be aware that mouse wheel is bound to "Paste from X clipboard" by default. To rebind the shortcut will introduce conflicts.

Steps to bind:
File -> Settings... -> Keymap -> Main menu -> Edit -> Find -> Show Usages
Right click on it and select "add Mouse Shortcut"